# Unable to delete folder on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, android, file-management, eclipse

I am struggling to delete a directory using Windows 8.

There is a directory that is used by Eclipse/ADT to developer android apps. It is in my user folder (c:\Users\Mark.android).

I have tried the following:

- Deleting the folder using `Del` key (nothing happens).
- Deleting in command prompt (as administrator) using `del` .android. I get the message:

  > The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
- Loading into safe mode and deleting the file manually and using `del` in the command prompt.

Is there something else I can try or am I stuck with this damn file forever?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Shift + Delete sometimes works for me (permanent deletion without the trash can)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had some errors on my disk that was causing this.

To fix this I did the following:

- Access my computer (Windows Key + E)
- Right click the C Drive
- Select properties
- Select the `Tools` tab
- Select `Check` under `Error checking`
- Ran the error check and rebooted to repair the drive

After this, I could delete the file properly.